# Remove duplicate values in a map Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary

For example, i have this:

```
{[dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], [dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], [dificultad, adios]=["alta", "abckdk"]}
```

which is a `Map<List<String>, List<String>>`, what i want to do is remove the repeated values on my map and have only one of those.

**Output expected**:

```
{[dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"], [dificultad, adios]=["alta", "abckdk"]}
```

I tried that, but is not working:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Map<List<String>, List<String>>>> it2 = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Map<List<String>, List<String>>> aux = it2.next();
            if(!it2.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(aux.getKey() + "  " + aux.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you define duplicate in this problem? What if the second entry is `[dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a", "x"]`? how the duplicate will be considered then? And which key do you want to keep and which one to exclude in case of duplicate? Too many unclear scenarios. Please add more precise description and focused question

Comment: What i mean , duplicate in my problem is [dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"] and [dificultad, adios]=["baja", "a"] are equals so i should have one of them and not both because they are the same @devReddit

Comment: If you're using map, how are you producing these duplicate entries with the same list as key? Such use of same list as key for all entries will result into only one entry in the map having the key with the value from the last entry.

Comment: Because i'm doing an interpreter with Antrl4 @devReddit

Comment: It is not possible to provide a meaningful answer because your Map has duplicate keys in the form of the same lists.